# Is it possible to chain directive scopes (e.g. obj.prop)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
  template: '<form novalidate class="form-inline" ng-submit="submit($event, building)">' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="form-control-static">{{label}}</label>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input name="input" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" />' +
      '</form>',
        scope: {
      label: "@",
      building: "=",
      model: "=",
      //type: "=",
        },
```

Right now I have to write something like this in the HTML:

```
<building-field label="name" building="building" model="building.name"></building-field>
```

I would like to simply it by just needing to add the `building` and the `label` (and then put them together inside the directive `ng-model="building.name`):

```
<building-field label="name" building="building"></building-field>
```

The problem is, I don't know how to pass two directive scopes and like them as `obj.prop`. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have anything special to do, `obj.prop` is supported. In your template:

```
<input name="input" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="building[label]" />
```

As a side note, you are binding `label` with a interpolation (type `@`). This means that as is, you will always have the string `"name"` in `scope.label`. If you want to actually pass the value of `name`, you need to use double curly brackets:

```
<building-field label="{{name}}" building="building"></building-field>
```

Comment: When I do `ng-model="building.label" ` the input doesn't show anymore. I think that's because label uses `@` and building uses `=`. I want the values of `obj` and `prop` to be taken from `building` and `label`.

Comment: @alexchenco got it, I updated my answer. What you want is `ng-model="building[label]"`

Comment: It worked! So the square brackets make the scopes with interpolation show in the attributes?

Comment: Well, think of it as normal javascript. In the HTML, `building` is what is in `$scope.building` and `label` is what is in `$scope.label`. So When in the HTML you write `building[label]`, the javascript executed is `$scope.building[$scope.label]` which is standard JS to read a property from an object (just like `a[i]` when you read an array)